# php -> MYSQL query can't figure out what is wrong getting error #1064

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to insert some values in the table the query is below:

```
Insert into 
auditlog (
          event,
          desc,
          userid,
          useripaddress,
          audittype
)
VALUES (
         'User Authenticated', 
         'Useradminsuccessfully logged in to the system', 
         '1', 
         '127.0.0.1','1'
)
```

It gives me the following error:
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc,userid,useripaddress,audittype)VALUES ('User Authenticated', 'User admin su' at line 1

However when i run the insert using PHPMYAdmin it does insert a value and the query generated is

```
INSERT INTO 
     `auditlog`(
              `event`, 
              `desc`, 
              `userid`, 
              `useripaddress`, 
              `audittype`) 
     VALUES (
              'User Authenticated', 
              'Useradminsuccessfully logged in to the system', 
              '1', 
              '127.0.0.1','1'
     )
```

The only difference i see is the quotes which i dont believe are needed. I don't understand where am i going wrong and am breaking my head now :):)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write SQL for a table that shares the same name as a protected keyword in MySql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706920/how-can-i-write-sql-for-a-table-that-shares-the-same-name-as-a-protected-keyword)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backticks are needed around `desc` because it is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html).

```
INSERT INTO auditlog (event, `desc`, userid, useripaddress, audittype)
VALUES (
    'User Authenticated',
    'Useradminsuccessfully logged in to the system',
    '1',
    '127.0.0.1',
    '1'
)
```

There is also no harm in adding backticks around the other column names if you aren't sure whether or not they are reserved words.

Comment: got it ...thnx...it works now!!! aahh didn't think desc can also be for descending ..i wanted to use short name for description...i just changed the column name to description to avoid any further issues. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of words that are reserved and needs to be backticked: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html